# fixing URL in Owncloud application to remove requirements to have index.php in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have apache 2.2.15.  In it I have a virtual directory for owncloud.  I am attempting to have http://cargobay.trekfederation.com, however when I type that, my system response with the Apache HTTP Server default page.  If I put in http://cargobay.trekfederation.com/index.php, it works.  In my .htaccess file, I have tried a series of different RewriteRules to no avail.

The httpd entry looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName cargobay.trekfederation.com
ServerAlias cargobay.trekfederation.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<Directory /var/www/html/owncloud>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The owncloud .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Version: 8.0.2
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 513M
php_value post_max_size 513M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
<IfModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv htaccessWorking true
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^apps/calendar/caldav\.php remote.php/caldav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/contacts/carddav\.php remote.php/carddav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
        ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/templates/404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/apache-rewrite-to-remove-index-php/658): you need to update `.htaccess` files **via ownCloud command line utility** (perhaps in addition to `systemctl restart apache2`), like this:

```
$ sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/owncloud/occ maintenance:update:htaccess

.htaccess has been updated
```

You have to specify the user with `sudo -u` (in my case it is `www-data` who is able to write into Apache directories).

Also check the directory where your `owncloud/` folder is (in my case `/var/www/html/owncloud/`).